# do we get compilation error if atomic builtin provided by gcc is not supported by underlying hardware or os?

Tags: c, gcc, synchronization, atomic

I am working on a opensource environment where my product can be used in any hardware . I am particularly working on logging and to make it atomic i am need to use checkandexchange aka testandset kind of functions . And since this program is writen on c and it run on linux os i am planning to go with gcc atomic buildins .

Will these build in macros throw an error if they are not supported or will they lead to run time problems?

I am a pure programmer and i have very minimal knowlegde about anything apart from coding . All i could able to understand from the manual is that these function does exactly am i am looking for .

Since this is a opensource project , i am worried about breaking it (build failure is better than run time issues)

I know i could have use linux kernel functions but then it doesn't provide compare and swap option .

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i explained my problem to my level best , i am not sure what u expect .

Comment: Am atomic type is special only in that the read/write access happen in one instruction. The `stdatomic.h` header guarantees this atomicity. Your title - `atomic builtin provided by gcc is not supported by underlying hardware or os` - is misleading.

Comment: seriously , read manually and try to use them

Comment: I repeat, change the title of this question.

Comment: it is not misleading and i am not changing  it

Answer (score 2):

If a particular builtin is not provided on a specific platform, gcc replaces it by a call to a function. You'd then have to provide this function or you'd get a link time error.

Using C11's `<stdatomic.h>` and a compiler version that supports it avoids that problem: if an instruction is not supported it will be emulated.